# How to make new Div inside list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

*I have find related answers, but not same like this question.* 
My question is how to make new Div inside list items only on `.widget-content` like given below?

Main **HTML**: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4eo2fa06/)

```
<div class="widget-content">
<ul>
<li>Test Content</li>
<li>Test Content</li>
<li>Test Content</li>

<li>Test Content</li>
<li>Test Content</li>
<li>Test Content</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

*I want to:*

```
 <div class="widget-content">
 <ul>
 <div class='new1'> <!--Want to Add New dive class 1-->
  <li>Test Content</li>
  <li>Test Content</li>
  <li>Test Content</li>
    </div>
 <div class='new2'> <!--Add New dive class 2-->
 <ul>
  <li>Test Content</li>
  <li>Test Content</li>
  <li>Test Content</li>
 </div>    
</ul>
</div>
```

Means add 2 Div, `<div class='new1'>` have first 3 child and `<div class='new2'>` have last 3 child/List items. How to do this simply by Jquery/JS ? 
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: how you recognize where we have to add that DIV

Comment: @tinka i mean, add 2 Div, <div class='new1'> have first 3 child and <div class='new2'> have last 3 child/List items. my question edited.

Comment: The way you've inserted your div element horribly breaks your DOM. For better context, explain why you wish to add this div, whether for display, functionality or both.

Comment: Why it is Hot(question title) ?.

Comment: @Screenack i wan to break it in  two different div, because HTLM structure output from Wp Plugin and i'm not able to change HTML, so trying do this by jqury/js

Comment: You wish to insert a div, right? Why a div element? And why do you want to break an unordered list? Sorry, this fundamentally does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this

```
var selectedIndex = 3;
$(".widget-content li").each(function (index) {
    if (index == selectedIndex) {
        $(this).prevAll().wrapAll("<div class='new1' />");
        $(this).nextAll().andSelf().wrapAll("<div class='new2' />");
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok i will try, please wait

Comment: Thanks, But, It not like this, according to my question we have to do this for `$(".widget-content)` not `$("li")`, because it will effect to others elements. so how to do this only on `$(".widget-content)`

Comment: hmmmm ok, just add $(".widget-content li") and it will not effect to other elements

Comment: Great, but if we choose First 4 list item for  `<div class='new1'/>` and last 2 for `<div class='new2'/>` so what we should do ?

Comment: you can define a parameter for selected index

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84880/discussion-between-aabira-and-kalkanbatuhan).

Comment: Thanks, Works very well

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="widget-content">
        <ul id="ul1"></ul>
</div>
```

js: i am assuming here count is 3

```
window.onload = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = 'row' + i;
        div.innerHTML = '<li>Test Content</li>\
    <li>Test Content</li>\
    <li>Test Content</li>';
        document.getElementById('ul1').appendChild(div);
    }

};
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jslight/8h2k6g8j/)

Comment: Thanks, but Fiddle Please.

Comment: I mean i want to aplly this js for only `.widget-content` not for all list item of Page, so how to do this for only `.widget-content`  and please provide fiddle link like this :http://jsfiddle.net/4eo2fa06/

Comment: this will apply only `ul1` id element not for all page

Comment: because you didn't change anything please copy code from here including html remove your html then try it is working in your fiddle i tried

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84875/discussion-between-aabira-and-tinka).

Comment: @Aabira you should add fiddle updated answer with fiddle