# Wrap List elements by class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

*I have asked related answer, but not same like this* question: [How to make new Div inside list items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31760566/4290783)

My question is how to break list items and add new Class find from list items, example below?

**Main HTML:** [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4eo2fa06/4/)

```
<div class="widget-content">
<ul>
<li><a class="label1" href="/lorem">lorem</a> Test Content</li>
<li><a class="label1" href="/lorem">lorem</a> Test Content</li>
<li><a class="label1" href="/lorem">lorem</a> Test Content</li>

<li><a class="label2" href="/lorem">lorem</a> Test Content</li>
<li><a class="label2" href="/lorem">lorem</a> Test Content</li>
<li><a class="label2" href="/lorem">lorem</a> Test Content</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

*I want to break list items by class like this:*

```
<div class="widget-content">

<ul class="label1"> <!--add class find from list-->
<li><a class="label1" href="/lorem">lorem</a> Test Content</li>
<li><a class="label1" href="/lorem">lorem</a> Test Content</li>
<li><a class="label1" href="/lorem">lorem</a> Test Content</li>
</ul>

<ul class="label2"> <!--add class find from list-->
<li><a class="label2" href="/lorem">lorem</a> Test Content</li>
<li><a class="label2" href="/lorem">lorem</a> Test Content</li>
<li><a class="label2" href="/lorem">lorem</a> Test Content</li>
</ul>

</div>
```

I mean break list items by class and add class to parent `ul` find from list items example given above. How to do this simply by Jquery/JS ? 

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/radoka/4/edit?html,css,js,console,output)***

```
$(".widget-content").each(function(){

  var $li = $(this).find("li").unwrap(); // unwrap removes the old UL wrapper
  var uniq = [];

  // Create a collection of unique "label*" classes:
  $li.find("[class^=label]").attr("class", function(i, v){
    if(!~$.inArray(v, uniq)) uniq.push(v);
  });

  // Group LI by A class, and wrap into a new UL with the same class
  $.each(uniq, function(i, klas){
    $("a."+klas).closest("li").wrapAll($("<ul/>",{class:klas}));
  });

});
```

Comment: But how to break list items by class? fiddle link please.

Comment: ok, any fiddle link example, trying to break list items by class