# Wrap/Break List elements by replace text to class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

My question is how to Wrap/Break list items by add Class find from list items text, example below?

My related question here: [Wrap List elements by class name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35920178/4290783)

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/yn60j368/)

```
<div class="widget-content">
    <ul>
        <li><span class="label"> demo-text1 </span> Test Content</li>
        <li><span class="label"> demo-text2 </span> Test Content</li>
        <li><span class="label"> demo-text1 </span> Test Content</li>

        <li><span class="label"> demo-text2 </span> Test Content</li>
        <li><span class="label"> demo-text1 </span> Test Content</li>
        <li><span class="label"> demo-text2 </span> Test Content</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

*I want to break list items like this:*

```
<div class="widget-content">
    <ul class="demo-text1">
        <li><span class="label"> demo-text1 </span> Test Content</li>
        <li><span class="label"> demo-text1 </span> Test Content</li>
        <li><span class="label"> demo-text1 </span> Test Content</li>

    </ul> <!-- Break part 1 -->

    <ul class="demo-text2">
        <!-- Break part 2 -->
        <li><span class="label"> demo-text2 </span> Test Content</li>
        <li><span class="label"> demo-text2 </span> Test Content</li>
        <li><span class="label"> demo-text2 </span> Test Content</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I mean break list items in two parts like second HTML example. Add class to both parent `ul` by replace text find from `class="label"`example given above (second HTML).

How can I do this simply by jQuery/JS ? Here is what I tried:

```
$(".widget-content").each(function() {
    var $li = $(this).find("li").unwrap(); // unwrap removes the old UL wrapper
    var uniq = [];

    // Create a collection of unique "label*" classes:
    $li.find("[class^=label]").attr("class", function(i, v) {
        if (!~$.inArray(v, uniq)) uniq.push(v);
    });
    // Group LI by A class, and wrap into a new UL with the same class
    $.each(uniq, function(i, klas) {
        $("a." + klas).closest("li").wrapAll($("<ul/>", {
            class: klas
        }));
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you always want to split the list in to two no matter how many `li` there are, or do you want to split it in to multiple groups of 3? Also, please add the JS code you've written yourself to solve the issue.

Comment: becz, I'm learning JS, i always practice, here is my try: https://jsfiddle.net/yn60j368/1/

Comment: That's fine, we're all still learning. It just helps people answer your question when they can see how you've attempted to solve it, and if there's any bugs in your code which can be easily fixed.

Comment: yes, multiple groups by Text from `class="label"`, means if there are different text on `class="label"` the please make new group. I mean split only when different text on `class="label"`, hope you understand :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.each()`, `$.each()`, `.html()` , `.text()`, `.trim()`

```js
var arr = []; // array to store `li` elements
var widget = $(".widget-content");

$(".widget-content li").each(function(index, el) {
  var html = el.outerHTML;
  // number at `label` text
  var curr = $(".label", this).text().trim().slice(-1);
  if (arr[curr - 1]) {
    arr[curr - 1].push(html)
  } else {
    arr[curr - 1] = [html];
  }
});

widget.html(""); // remove existing `html`

$.each(arr, function(key, val) {
  var li = val.join("");
  $(".widget-content").append($("<ul/>", {
    html: li,
    "class":$(li).eq(0).find(".label").text().trim()
  }))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="widget-content">
  <ul>
    <li><span class="label"> demo-text1 </span> Test Content</li>
    <li><span class="label"> demo-text2 </span> Test Content</li>
    <li><span class="label"> demo-text1 </span> Test Content</li>

    <li><span class="label"> demo-text2 </span> Test Content</li>
    <li><span class="label"> demo-text1 </span> Test Content</li>
    <li><span class="label"> demo-text2 </span> Test Content</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, but trying to add class to parent `ul`  by Text from class `class="label"`, i mean find text on `class="label"` then replace the text to class, then add this class to each parent `ul`

Comment: and there are 6 `li` items, why 4 lists? i'm trying to group list items to `demo-text1` and `demo-text2` class on `ul`

Comment: Please check my second HTML example on question, i want this output.